# Infopath cannot see target form library for publish

Tags: 2010, infopath, template

When trying to publish a template as an update to an existing form library in SharePoint 2010, InfoPath 2010 does not show the existing form library in the list of available form libraries.

I created the form library by saving a pre-existing library as a template. I then made the new library using that template (data included). I opened the "forms" folder from the newly created library and downloaded a copy of the template.xsn file locally. I am trying to change the publish location of the template form to the newly created library (it is still set to publish to the old library).

The following steps occur when I attempt to publish the alternate version of this template to its new location:

1. File>Publish>SharePoint Server
2. Paste in URL of site that contains the new copy of form library template (hit next)
3. Select "Form Library" from the "What do you want to Create Or Modify?" prompt
4. Select "Update the form template in an existing form library" from the "What do you want to do?" prompt
5. Target library is not listed in the "Form Library to update" box.
6. Change to "Create a new form library" in the "What do you want to do" prompt
7. Type in the same name as the existing library and hit "Next"
8. The following warning appears: "A list, survey, discussion board, or library with that name already exists on this site. Enter another name."

So clearly the library exists, but for some reason InfoPath does not display it to me in the list of existing libraries. I have tried the following steps to fix this issue:

- Clear SSL state and reauthenticate to the SharePoint site in I.E.
- Reboot system and attempt to re publish
- Use the "infopath /cache clearall" command to start InfoPath from the run prompt.
- Checked the SharePoint site to be certain that the new library is indeed a form library (it is).

None of these steps have resolved the problem.

Any suggestions would be very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... so I'll answer since it's now resolved... The answer in this situation is "wait longer".

Looks like it was some kind of strange replication issue or *something*. It could be the way the domain is set up, the fact that I sit outside of it... I don't know.

So just keep waiting. It should eventually appear.